# Django - AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'court_number'

Tags: django

My edit view in my application won't update the court details whenever I want to edit it. I keep getting the error below. Adding, Viewing & Deleting functions are working okay. I cant find a solution on the other S/O answers. Some help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

```
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'court_number'
```

model.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Court(models.Model):
    court_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Court Number.')
    accused_person = models.ForeignKey(AccusedPerson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Accused Person')
    court = models.CharField(choices=COURTS, max_length=255, verbose_name='Court')
    court_verdict = models.CharField(choices=VERDICT, max_length=50, verbose_name='Court Status')
    scheduled_on = models.DateField(verbose_name='Scheduled On')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Police Officer')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date Created')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Date Updated')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.court_number)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Court'
```

forms.py

```
class EditCourtInfoForm(forms.Form):
    court_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'court_number', 'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'name': 'court_number', 'placeholder': 'Court Number'}))
    accused_person = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'accused_person', 'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'name': 'accused_person', 'placeholder': 'Accused Person'}))
    court = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COURTS, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'court', 'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'name': 'court', 'placeholder': 'Court'}))
    court_verdict = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VERDICT, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'court_verdict', 'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'name': 'court_verdict', 'placeholder': 'Verdict'}))
    scheduled_on = forms.DateField(required=True, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'id': 'scheduled_on', 'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'name': 'scheduled_on', 'placeholder': 'Scheduled On'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditCourtInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['accused_person'].choices = [(e.pk, f"{e.first_name}" + ' ' + f"{e.middle_name}" + ' ' + f"{e.last_name}") for e in AccusedPerson.objects.all()]
    
    class Meta:
        model = Court
        fields = ['court_number', 'accused_person', 'court', 'court_verdict', 'scheduled_on']
```

views.py

```
def EditCourtInfo(request, id):
    court = Court.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditCourtInfoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            context = {'has_error': False}
            court_number = form.cleaned_data['court_number']
            accused_person = form.cleaned_data['accused_person']
            court = form.cleaned_data['court']
            court_verdict = form.cleaned_data['court_verdict']
            scheduled_on = form.cleaned_data['scheduled_on']
            print(scheduled_on)

            court.court_number = court_number # The problem
            court.accused_person = AccusedPerson.objects.get(pk=int(accused_person))
            court.court = court
            court.court_verdict = court_verdict
            court.scheduled_on = scheduled_on
            court.created_by = request.user.profile

            if not context['has_error']:
                court.save()
                messages.success(request, '✅ Court Record Successfully Updated!')
                return redirect('OfficerCourtInfo')
                    
        else:
            messages.error(request, '⚠️ Court Record Was Not Updated!')
            return redirect('EditCourtInfo', id=id)
    
    else:
        form = EditCourtInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'Officer Edit Court.html', {'form':form, 'court':court})
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `court` is a string, so `court.court_number` is invalid. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: It seems that this line returns string `court = form.cleaned_data['court']`

Comment: Also, you use the variable name `court` twice for different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you have

```
    court = Court.objects.get(id=id)
```

but then later

```
            court = form.cleaned_data['court']
```

So you are re-using a variable for a different purpose. You could fix this problem by using a different variable for one of these. However, you are making this much more complicated than you need to. The form will already take care of editing the `Court` object for you:

```
def EditCourtInfo(request, id):
    court = Court.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditCourtInfoForm(request.POST, instance=court). # pass the court object to the form

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # just save the form
            messages.success(request, '✅ Court Record Successfully Updated!')
            return redirect('OfficerCourtInfo')
        else:
            messages.error(request, '⚠️ Court Record Was Not Updated!')
            return redirect('EditCourtInfo', id=id)
    
    else:
        form = EditCourtInfoForm()
        return render(request, 'Officer Edit Court.html', {'form':form, 'court': court})
```

You will need to change your form to extend `ModelForm` instead of `Form`:

```
class EditCourtInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

This code is untested, so I may have missed something. I suggest checking out the Django documentation to fill in any gaps in your understanding. You might even consider using a [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) instead.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice. This solved my problem. However my previous solution  also worked as well as soon as i changed the word `court = Court.objects.get(id=id)` to something like `court_details = Court.objects.get(id=id)`